# Html Select Box Get value from mysql

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, select, drop-down-menu

Hi I have a stored value in mysql from a select box. When i call a edit page I would like the select box to populate with the value i have stored in mysql

```
$taskCompany = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['taskCompany']); This returns 1 

<select id="taskCompany" required name="taskCompany" class="form-control">

    <option value="" disabled selected>Select a Company</option>
    <option value="1">building</option>
    <option value="2">maintenace</option>
</select></div>
```

I would like the select box to show the correct option when loading the edit page. I do not store any select option in the database values or text just the value that is select when job was created. 
Thanks Jon

Comment: Is it me or are `I have a stored value in mysql from a select box` and `I do not store any select option in the database values or text` contradicting each other

Comment: you are not storing any value in database ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php $taskCompany = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['taskCompany']); ?>

<select id="taskCompany" required name="taskCompany" class="form-control">

    <option value="" disabled selected>Select a Company</option>
    <option value="1" <?php if($taskCompany == 1) echo "selected='selected'"; ?>>building</option>
    <option value="2" <?php if($taskCompany == 2) echo "selected='selected'"; ?>>maintenace</option>
</select></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply but it does not seem to work. I have setup a fiidle take a look [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/cqh2wqu1/)

Comment: add jquery library in your fiddle and remove the script tag from fiddle's script area

Comment: Thanks but did not want to use jquery I have answered my own question my adding and is statement `<?php if ($row['taskCompany'] == '1') {$select ='selected'; }else{$select2 ='selected';}; ?>` Thanks

Comment: check the modified answer

Answer (score 1):

I'd I have understood correctly, you have he value/values in your *MySQL* database and you want them to be shown in your drop down list:
You could do it like:

```
<option value = "1" <?php if($taskCompany == 1) echo "select='selected'";?>>building</option>
```

Or if you have the names coming from the database too.

```
<select id="taskCompany" required name="taskCompany" class="form-control">

<option>SELECT</option>
<?php
$res = musql_query("SELECT * FROM yourtablename");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res))
{
$taskCompany = $row['taskCompany'];
$co_name = $row['taskCompanyName'];
?>
<option value = "<?php echo $taskCompany; ?>" ><?php echo co_name; ?></option>
<?php } ?>
```

Here I have used `$co_name` to be displayed as a name assuming that you have *building*, *maintenance* etc stored in your database.

> This is for the time being, as I wanted to demonstrate but Please
>   consider mysqli/PDO as mysql_* is deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this

```
<?php foreach($taskCompany as $row){ ?>
    <option value="unique id for select options">name for select options</option>
<?php } ?>
```